# condition_vairable::wait_for() question using Stroustrup example

Tags: c++

The following example code is from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 1234.  I'm questioning if this is errata not listed in [his errata document](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html).  The code throws a system error due to timeout, when from what I have read about `wait_for` on [the specs page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) can return spuriously.  Therefore, `not_empty == false` and it may not be the result of a duration timeout.

Can anyone confirm this would be the behavior or if this code reflects how `wait_for` behaves?

```
template<typename T>
void Sync_queue::get(T& val, steady_clock::duration d)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    bool not_empty = cond.wait_for(lck,d,[this] { return !q.empty(); });
    if (not_empty) {
        val=q.front();
        q.pop_front();
    }
    else
        throw system_error{"Sync_queue: get() timeout"};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to this part:

```
1)  ... It may also be unblocked spuriously.
```

The crucial detail is that this is describing only `wait_for`'s ***first*** overload, that's what "1)" means, which does ***not*** use a predicate.

The 2nd overload is the one that has a predicate parameter. The second overload gets described below, and it defers to `wait_until`; which, if you follow along, defines this overload unambiguously: either the timeout expires or the predicate gets satisfied. And this is done so in a manner handles spurious wakeups correctly, in the expected fashion.

Comment: I see now regarding the predicate overload: This overload may be used to ignore spurious awakenings.